# Is there an equivalent of '==' from Java in EE 6 JSF EL

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, el

I am working in JSF 2 with Primefaces 3.4 and I found an example where '==' in my xhtml does not behave like '==' in Java. I could not find details for '==' operator in Java EE 6 documentation. What does it exactly do? Is there an equivalent of Java '==' for Objects in EL?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also use `eq` instead of `==` in EL.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes, it is what?  There were two options given.

Comment: From EL, using `==` is **the same of** using `==` for primitives and `equals` for objects, like `String`s. Did you at least tried it?

Comment: Also, this is EL, it is not just for Java EE nor JSF, it also works in EL `${}` used in a servlet container like Tomcat.

Comment: @Luiggi Is there an equivalent to `==` for object references in EL?

Comment: Sotirios- this is exactly what I was after Thank you Luiggi for extra clarifications.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis AFAIK no, and if your class doesn't implement `equals` it will use default `Object#equals` that ends using `==`.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/javaee6/ExpressionLanguage.shtml

Comment: Edited the question to more reflect my problem.

Comment: @PM77-1 IMO roseindia.net teaches JSF and related technologies in the wrong way. If you want to refer to a good resource about EL, use [StackOverflow EL's wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead.

Comment: @user2511414 AFAIK `is` is not an EL keyword nor a valid operator. Refer to [EL Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el006.htm#BNAIK).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh sorry, I just got it wrong with another tag libraries, sorry, thanks for notify, good catch :)

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166890). "'==' in my xhtml does not behave like '==' in Java" isn't true unless your expectations are incorrect. I suggest you solve *that* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent of Java '==' for Objects in EL?

Looks like it is not, but you don't really need it. EL `==` (and `eq`) will use the `equals` method when comparing object references, and it already supports `null` comparison. If your class happens to not override `equals`, then it will use [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) that ends using Java `==` for equality check.

If your class happens to override `equals` method, make sure to write a good implementation. As example:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (...) {
        //add here the rest of the equals implementation...
    }
    return false;
}
```

More info:

- [Java EE tutorial: Expression Language: Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el005.htm#BNAIK)

Comment: I know I can use equals, but my question is to bypass it and use '==' instead. If this is not possible, then I will wait a bit more (in case someone has a genius answer) and accept your answer.

Comment: @jedrus07 maybe if your post your actual problem you could get a more accurate answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Mendoza The **link** *Java EE tutorial: Expression Language: Operators* is **broken**. Please update it.

Comment: @OO7 link updated. Thanks. I recommend you to update links whenever you can, not only here but in other Q/As as well.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Ok I'll.