# How to write if else condition using ternary operator in jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I want to write a if else condition using ternary in JSTL. I did it using jsp.

My code is using jsp:

```
<%= relAttributeValue != "false" && !relAttributeValue.equals("false") ? "rel=\"nofollow\"" : "" %>
```

How can I achieve it using jstl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), EL in short, since that's the component that allows you use `${something}` expressions, while JSTL is a tag library which gives you tag components like `<c:set>`.

In EL, you can do it like this:

```html
<c:set var="ternaryResult"
    value="${(relAttributeValue != 'false') ? 'rel=\"nofollow\"' : ''}" />
```

Note that in EL you don't need to worry about comparing references using `==` like in Java. More info on this: [Is there an equivalent of '==' from Java in EE 6 JSF EL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19498926/1065197)