# JSP if certain condition, then include page

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP I want to include another page if a certain condition is true. So far, I have this:

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="'tru2e'=='true'">
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">

                <jsp:include page="somestuff.jsp" />

            </div>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

The issue that I'm running into (not even sure if I'm doing this right in the first place), is that even though true2e is not equal to true, it's still including the jsp. What am I missing?

Comment: It's explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14580120/205936)

Comment: Looks like your EL is wrong. It should be `<c:when test="${tru2e}">`.

Comment: @Bitman refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19498926/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it can only take boolean values? Can I not make comparisons?

Comment: If your variable is already a `boolean`, then use it as a `boolean`. If it holds a `String` with value `"true"`, it should be a `boolean` instead. If it is a `String` with a different value, use `${theString eq 'desiredValue'}`, but remember to use EL.